# Search DAM assets and Cq pages using lastModified date | QueryBuilder

Tags: aem, query-builder, last-modified

I am querying the cq pages and assets based on the last modified date.
Here is the the text that has to be put in query builder debugger:

```
fulltext=geometrix
1_group.p.or=true

1_group.1_group.p.and=true
1_group.1_group.path=/content
1_group.1_group.type=cq:Page
1_group.1_group.relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/cq:lastModified
1_group.1_group.relativedaterange.lowerBound=-1M

1_group.2_group.p.and=true
1_group.2_group.path=/content/dam
1_group.2_group.type=dam:Asset
1_group.2_group.relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/cq:lastModified
1_group.2_group.relativedaterange.lowerBound=-1M
```

It doesn't work.
Here I have to apply lowerbound on both cq:pages and dam assets.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does anyone have a response. Its a simple thing but has taken a while.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is full right except the thing that dam:asset don't have `cq:lastModified` property but it has `jcr:lastModified`.

So instead of using:

```
1_group.2_group.relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/cq:lastModified
```

you can use:

```
1_group.2_group.relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/jcr:lastModified
```

and it will start working.