# AEM 6.2:: Search cq:Page and dam:Asset with a specific tag and ordered by jcr:created

Tags: aem, query-builder

I am trying to create PredicateGroup that would search all cq:Page and dam:Asset under respective paths. Further, these nodes are tagged with a specific tag and ordered by jcr:created.

Here is what I have written:

```
group.1_group.p.and=true
group.1_group.path=/content/some/path
group.1_group.type=cq:Page
group.1_group.1_property=@jcr:content/cq:tags
group.1_group.1_property.value=root:some/tag
group.p.or=true
group.2_group.p.and=true
group.2_group.path=/content/dam/some/path
group.2_group.type=dam:Asset
group.2_group.1_property=@jcr:content/metadata/cq:tags
group.2_group.1_property.value=root:some/tag
```

and it won't work on query debugger. I have also looked at this URL [Search DAM assets and Cq pages using lastModified date | QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655619/search-dam-assets-and-cq-pages-using-lastmodified-date-querybuilder) and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Right now, I haven't added the condition for sorting because I was trying to go step by step.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on the scope of your query you may want to consider traversing the repository using the `ResourceResolver` instead of using queries.

Comment: Do they work separate? That is, searching only for Pages (first query) and only for Assets (second query)?

Comment: Yeah they do work separately. The reason why I am trying to create it as one query is because they have to be sorted based on jcr:created. I can search pages and assets independently and then create a consolidated list and then sort them based on jcr:created but I am not sure if that would be quicker or a query.